# Не работает часть функционала на сайте

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, http, https

Может вопрос не совсем для сюда, но я не знаю куда обратиться еще. Работаю над одним сайтом и часть функционала не работает, точнее не принимаются get-запросы. Такое происходит только на рабочем компе, на личном все отлично. Рабочий мощнее, чем личный, но я сомневаюсь что в этом проблема. В чем может быть проблема? Порты какие-то не открыты или на Вин 10 политика безопасности такая?

Comment: крайне мало конкретики, какой используется сервер, бэкенд?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ думаю дело не в бэке, а в компе, на всех компах проверял, не работает только на рабочем

Comment: все гет запросы, или какие то конкретные? cachebreaker добавляли?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ конкретно с бэка и только те, что требуют действий пользователя, фоновые запросы, например поиск контента, загрузка картинок и т.д. работают нормально

Comment: Рабочий сисадмин контролирует?

Comment: @Coder сомневаюсь, комп новый, да и проект и на localhost не работает

Comment: Аккаунт у Вас административный на компе?

Comment: @Coder да, администратор

Comment: Попробуйте отключить защитник и убрать другие виды ограничений - контроля UAC и прочее, если что есть - например, внешний антивирус и проверьте правильность формирования записей в hosts локальным сервером и доступность 80 порта.